# how to determine whether a given docker environment is based on libcontainer or lxe

Tags: docker

When I run sudo docker version I get the following output:

```
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8
```

From this, I have no way of telling whether my docker environment is based on libcontainer or lxe.

Are there any deeper command to ascertain this level of detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker since version 1.0 has been defaulted to the "native" driver which is libcontainer, unless your docker daemon is started with `--exec-driver=lxc`, you are using the libcontainer version.

Check your config file and the output of `ps -ef | grep docker`

Answer (score 0):

docker-info provides useful information.
Execution driver "native" is libcontainer.

```
docker info | grep Execution
```